# Type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

In my VB.Net project, which has refrences to Infragistics assemblies like:

- Infragistics.Shared.v3.1.dll
- Infragistics.Win.v3.1.dll
- Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.v3.1.dll
- Infragistics2.Excel.v10.1.dll
- etc.

But in my system`s GAC folder these assemblies are not present. When I am trying to build the solution of the project, I am getting errors like:

> Type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo' is not defined

Please help me, how to overcome these errors.

Answer (score 2):

Infragistics.XXXXX.**v3.1**? Seriously?
Are you using the correct references?

Try to upgrade to the same version **10.1** for every control
(References, Add Reference, Select the Infragistics.xxxx.v10.1.dll in place of the version 3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The assemblies that are references are from NetAdvantage 2004 Volume 1.  For your project to compile and run without changes you need to install NetAdvantage 2004 Volume 1 and this will only install on Windows XP and older.  The installer is downloadable from the [My Keys and Downloads](https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/keys-and-downloads/) page on the Infragistics website if you have your product key registered to your account.

Note that NetAdvantage 2004 Volume 1 was for .NET Framework 1.x and Visual Studio 2003.  If you are indeed using that and you don't have a key for NetAdvantage 2004 Volume 1, you could install NetAdvantage for .NET 2007 Volume 1 which is the last volume that supported .NET Framework 1.x and is available from the [archived downloads](http://www.infragistics.com/products/downloads/archived) page.

If you have moved to Visual Studio 2005 or later, then you could download the latest version of NetAdvantage and use that.  For this, click the link to try on the [NetAdvantage for Windows Forms](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/) product page.

If you install a newer version of NetAdvantage than what is currently referenced you will need to update the references in your project.  In 2007 Volume 1, there is a project upgrade utility that can be used to do this.  In 2012 Volume 1, there is a version utility that can be used to do this.